# Is there a way to create a const Uint8List in Dart?

Tags: dart, constants

Is it possible to specify literal typed_data in Dart?  It would be very useful if one could do something like:

```
const Uint8List foo = const Uint8List [0, 1, 2, 3];
```

Comment: What would you want to use it for?

Comment: have you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported. There aren't too many advantages in Dart using `const` anyway.

Comment: I'd be happy just to have a way to write a `Uint8List` literal :)

Comment: Default parameter values is a common and very useful use case.

Comment: @cbreezier, aggree. That's why I'm here.